# compare and delete on an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to write a short code to read a .m file(testin1.m) into an array, and search for a particular word( 'auto'). if match is found,delete it. i have the following code, please help me figure out my mistake.

```
fid = fopen('testin1.m');
 txt = textscan(fid,'%s');
fclose(fid);
m_file_idx = 1;
data=['auto'];
B=cellstr(data);
 for idx = i : length(txt)
 A=txt{i};
 is_auto=isequal(A, B);
 if is_auto==0
 txt{i}=[];
 end
end
```

if txt{i}=auto then it should delete that row.

Comment: Do you just want to delete the word 'auto' or the entire line containing that word?

Comment: the entire line containing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AK4749's answer is absolutely correct in showing where you went wrong. I'll just add an alternative solution to yours, which is shorter:

```
C = textread('testin1.m', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
C = C(cellfun(@isempty, regexp(C, 'auto')));
```

That's it!

*EDIT #1: answer modified to remove the lines that contains the word 'auto', not just the word itself.

*EDIT #2: answer modified to accept regular expressions.**

Comment: can i use  expr ='\.DataType[ =]+''auto'''; and C = C(cellfun(@isempty, strfind(C, expr))); to delete all the strings that has a .DataType=auto?

Comment: No, `strfind` doesn't accept regular expressions. For that you'll have  to use `regexp` instead. I've revised the answer accordingly.

Comment: so if i use C = C(cellfun(@isempty, regexp(C, expr))); it will delete the entire string matching expr?

Answer (score 2):

This is an error i have hit many amany many many times:

when you set `txt(i) = []`, you change the length of the array. Your for loop condition is no longer valid.

A better option would be to use the powerful indexing features:

`A(find(condition)) = [];`

or account for the change in length:

```
A(i) = [];
i--; % <-- or i++, it is too early to think, but you get the idea
```

EDIT: I just noticed you were also using `A` in your program. mine was just some random variable name, not the same A you might be using

Answer (score 1):

When you set `txt(i) = []`, you changed the length of the array but the loop indexing does not account for the change. You can use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?s_tid=doc_12b#bq7egb6-1) to avoid the loop and the problem.

Example:

```
wordToDelete = 'auto';
txt = {'foo', 'bar', 'auto', 'auto', 'baz', 'auto'}
match = strcmp(wordToDelete, txt)
txt = txt(~match)
```

Output:

```
txt = 
    'foo'    'bar'    'auto'    'auto'    'baz'    'auto'
match =
     0     0     1     1     0     1
txt = 
    'foo'    'bar'    'baz'
```